# Consultar y contar registros relacionados con laravel

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-7, model-view-controller

Este tipo de consulta no se como ejecutarla en laravel. les explico;

En mysql tengo una tabla de eventos y otra de estados, y utiliza una tabla que hace de intermediario para asignarles las relaciones que hay entres ellas.

Tabla relacion: Event_Status

```
--------------------------
id| event_id | status_id |
1      1         1
2      2         4      
3      3         1
4      4         2
5      5         2
6      6         4
```

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer una consulta que me cuente TODOS los eventos con "x"  cantidad estado de acuerdo a su tabla de relación Event_Status?.

> Mi objetivo es tener una lista como ejemplo esta: [21, 11, 2, 3]

**Edito:** Lo que he logrado hasta ahora seria esto:

consultar registros que solo tengan relacion con tabla estados. Luego comprobar quienes tienen estado id: 1, y finalize contando cuantos fueron.

```
        $data = Event::whereHas('status', function($q){
            $q->where('status_id', '=', '1');
        })->count();
```

El detalle es que tendria que hacer una consulta para cada id de estado distinto y luego ponerlos en un array...

Comment: Gracias por responder y sugerencia, editare la pregunta para tomar como referencia lo logrado hasta ahora.

Answer (score 0):

Al final esta fue mi solución

```
//Consulta: Cuenta cuantos registros hay con su respectivo estado. 
Status::withCount('events')->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->pluck('events_count');

 //Salida: tomando de ejemplo los registros de la tabla mostrada
 events_count: [2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: No olvides marcarla como aceptada por favor